# Using Android as network server

Tags: networking

I want to use my Android device as a network server. In the same kind of way you would make it a Wi-Fi hotspot, but I don't want to allow connected computers to access the internet, I would like them to be able to communicate together.

Possible uses:

1. Playing games via LAN (e.g., Quake)
2. Allow computers to share files
3. Bonjour (Macs)
4. etc...

Is there any way to achieve this? Any apps out there that will set up a wireless network server?

Comment: Your device is rooted or not?

Comment: yes, sorry device is rooted.

Comment: What kind of device is it? Does it have traditional tethering ability already?

Comment: Nexus S running CM9. It does have tethering. But I don't want to allow access to the internet.

Comment: @ThomasClayson If your device is rooted, firewall is the solution... Edit IPtables to block internet access of those connections.. Done!

Comment: Could you post an answer to show me how to do that exactly please? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [WiFi Tether](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.android.wifi.tether) app to create Wi-Fi hotspot. It features *Access Control* using which you can allow/**deny** clients to use mobile data.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick search for "server" on the Android marketplace, and most of the results seem to be basic file servers, web servers and FTP servers. These will help with sharing files, using your Android device to store the files, but probably not much else.

Here [is one that I found](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sygem.android.shareme_free&feature=search_result)  that supports [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) (Universal Plug n' Play), and DLNA (Digital Living Network Alliance),  and is designed for images, video and music, and states that Xbox 360 and PS3 are supported, although it doesn't state that you can use it for games on those consoles, and the screenshots don't seem to have anything about games.

Now I'm assuming that nearly all of these apps will require a network to be in place, that is, all devices would be on Wi-Fi with your router (your homehub or whatever you use for all your devices to connect to the web, assuming you don't have a separate modem), so I don't think that these apps will make your Android like a Wi-Fi hotspot, just a server in the sense of a central machine that stores the data that others use. The actual data connections would be via the router, just all going to/from the Android.